# localhost redirect to original url

Tags: magento-1.7, redirect

I have a web in a server, but I want update magento. To update I want copy the original magento in localhost, but I am having problems by redirect.

I explain my process:

1. I downloaded all content magento in my server.
2. I upload to my server in localhost all content.
3. I create in /etc/apache/sites-available a file to run my web.
4. I comprobe that it ran (with an error but ran).
5. I copy my sql script and run the script in my local database.
6. When I load my web in localhost it redirect to original magento.

I think that exists something in database that redirect my localhost to original because if I don't import the database, It redirect me well. But I don´t know that is the problem.

Comment: Have you checked if you've got an .htaccess inside the base directory interfering?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update our base URLs in the core_config_data database table.

This article explains how to do this: https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Update+Site+URL+in+core_config_data+after+you+move+to+a+new+server+or+change+domains

Comment: I change this but it do the same

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your database server or run this in PhpMyAdmin:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://localhost/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://localhost/' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

And then clean your cache.

Magento uses the database configuration to get the site url. It redirect all other urls to that url. So your Magento configuration is still redirecting you to the url stored in the database. With the script above we set the url in the configuration to http://localhost/.

I would advice to not just use localhost (Magento/Cookies behave weird sometimes). Instead you could make a local domain like localhost.com to redirect to your local server. You can use the host file for this.

Comment: I change this but it do the same

Comment: Have you cleared your var folder

Answer (score 0):

First of all in app/etc/env.php  change server database detail to your localhost database detail like as follows

```
'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'dbname' => 'mage2351',
                'username' => 'root',
                'password' => 'root',
                'active' => '1',
                'driver_options' => [

                ]
            ]
        ]
```

Chnage dbname,host,username , password of your mysql detail in above array

and than change urls in core_config_data

with following querries

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://localhost/yourlocalprojectfoldername' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = 'http://localhost/yourlocalprojectfoldername' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` = 'web/secure/base_url';
```